# When users treat me like dirt - what should I do?

Tags: discussion

I've been called "a troll", "a jerk", and other very helpful epithets by some of the users here who seem to think that understanding words you're using is too much to ask.

I can accept criticism if it is constructive, but I won't allow this behavior to continue.

Please advise what my options are if I want to remove all of the content I contributed to this site and close my account. If I need to file a lawsuit against SE for derogatory language and defamation to make that happen - I'll do that.

If the user in question is adult enough to apologize I'll consider only demanding removal of the offending content.

Comment: Dude? I in hope our long history together you have found me to be fair and even handed.  I know you and I have cultural differences as people, I still hope we respect each other as people.  But throwing away all your hard work and effort because some new people are taking anonymous shots at the top?  Go ahead and be insulted; flag the garbage posts and we will clean it up; but don't destroy your creation because you are having a bad day.  I have been away from site (I moved and remodeled a house) but I can't imagine you will feel like this in another few days.

Comment: You clearly have more experience and knowledge than most users on the net and especially this site; I hope you'll take a couple of days and think over what you are suggesting.

Comment: Well my 2 cents ... one is here because one likes it. This is not a day job that gets one paid or runs the house. Be here while you enjoy it. Why be upset over what others type.

Comment: Please [contact us directly](http://money.stackexchange.com/contact) to talk about this. Let's not do anything hasty, we'll see what's going on and fix whatever needs fixing.

Comment: @Dheer I'm upset because I'm being called names and degraded for trying to help people. The same people that go on to write about me as a "troll" on this very meta site just because they're not capable of expressing themselves.

Comment: @littleadv I've contacted you privately, please check your email, and _please_ do not proceed with trying to remove all of your posts.

Comment: I apologize for the words I used.  I don't know why you seem to think I hold some sort of grudge against you.  My constructive criticism: the generally high quality of your posts is frequently degraded by your curt and at times outright rude tone.

Comment: I am not sure why you are miffed if someone calls you names ? You should realize that internet gives anonymity to trolls, who would be afraid to say the same things to your face. This is an unhealthy side effect you have got to deal with. You get miffed, you only hurt yourself. And I do support what @BrenBarn says. `Do not do unto others as you would that they should do unto you`

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I decided not to give the idiots the satisfaction. I'll stay here and will provide the excellent answers as I always provide. And if the imbeciles have problems with that - screw them.

And those who call me troll - you don't know what a troll is. I'll show you.

Comment: This is good news that you will stay and continue to set the bar with knowledge.  I respectfully ask that you don't call out users by name.  If you want to take your shots at me you have my permission, but I cannot allow your posts to insult other people.  Our community should be built on mutual respect and civility.  It is my job as a mod to remove such content from any post by anybody.

Comment: @littleadv I see plenty of reasons why you shouldnt, but mainly because you *are* an adult and should act like one even if other people dont. If a small child throws a tantrum or yells some stupid name at you in public, no reasonable adult would ever argue that that justifies them yelling names or throwing a tantrum right back. do I really need to trot out the phrase about "lowering yourself to their level"? for heaven's sake, GROW UP, get a thicker skin, and ignore stupid people. It's nothing personal, but acting childish won't help.

Comment: @littleadv Oh grow up. If you act like them just because you cant just ignore people ON THE INTERNET then you have no right to complain about them. The comments above are right: youre super helpful and knowledgeable but sometimes (often) youre pretty rude and immature, this being an example. If you won't be an adult then you shouldnt complain when others do. All I can say about it.

Comment: I'm not complaining, I'm frustrated. It appears that once I become a bit more than an average user I immediately become target for the trolls - and the mods don't seem to care or do anything about that. Doesn't encourage me to be too helpful. Look at @quanty - the person is crazy and obsessed, and although he actually wrote down 'Delete Me' in his profile - he's still writing horrible things all around and the mods just let him. Why would I behave differently then? What for? Why should I bother helping people then?

Comment: @MrChrister you can try and answer my question too. I know you prefer to bury your head in the sand - but do make an effort.

Comment: Happy to answer:  ignore the trolls.  Flag garbage and a mod will get to it.  We have to browse the site like you, so we miss stuff.  We don't leave vitriolic remarks from anybody.  If you find one, flag it.  If you leave one, it will (hopefully) get flagged.

Answer (score 12):

We *strongly* advise communities to involve moderators through flags, or contact us directly when a dispute with another user arises. We're all here to have fun and learn from one another, but sometimes disputes *do* happen - it happens any time you put humans together on a cooperative effort, no matter how nice they might be individually.

This is a *very* good example of an instance where the moderators should have been involved (click 'flag' then click 'other' and explain what's going on), and if unsatisfied there, [contacting us directly](https://money.stackexchange.com/contact). Once a dispute like this gets to meta, *groupthink ensues*, and it tends to deteriorate from there quite rapidly.

Folks, *please* - avoid pointing out specific users in cases like this. Instead, merely describe the *behavior and circumstances* - if the moderators want a specific example there are means to provide that privately.

Otherwise, the feelings of *awesome* people get hurt, and that's not why we're here.

I've answered the technical aspects of your question [in my answer here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2018/does-cc-by-sa-allow-you-to-revoke-rights-to-answers/2020#2020), and I've done quite a bit of clean up. There's no reason to preserve a point in history where folks just .. weren't quite at their best.

Let's concede that an unfortunate series of mistakes were made, but all of us *really* love this site and what we're building here, and nothing warrants tearing down that amount of awesomeness. Mistakes are that, just mistakes - something we learn from so this doesn't repeat itself.

Comment: Thank you for joining the discussion. As a lead contributor, *awesome* is the right word for littleadv and his contributions.

Answer (score 8):

I apologise for posting this as an answer, as it is really more of a comment. I'll certainly take the hit to my reputation if that's appropriate.

Littleadv, I sincerely hope you do not leave. Your reputation here is well-earned. Your answers are insightful and have taught me a great deal. If you do decide you have to leave, I hope you leave your answers in place because they are informative and valuable.

On other, non-stackexchange sites, I've been trolled, had somewhat strange threats made which were meant to put my employment in jeopardy, and had my life specifically threatened. So I would understand if you chose to leave and to delete (or have someone else delete) your posts. It's unlikely that you'll feel better in a day or in a week, but I do hope that your current frustration some day passes, and you are able to resume your excellent contributions.

We as a community need to do a better job of making sure interactions never get anywhere close to this. money.stackexchange.com helped me through an incredibly difficult period of my life and I have always appreciated the care and effort people, including litteadv, put in to their answers.

Comment: +1 good answer. And I agree with the sentiment expressed.

Comment: Meta posts don't affect rep ;)

Answer (score 2):

Is "Rodney King" too long ago to quote here? Can't we all just get along?

I read the board and proactively do what I can to maintain order, as do my colleagues, MrChrister and JohnFX. What we miss, hopefully gets flagged and we respond to that.

I've always erred on the side of kindness, preferring to delete any name calling, or editing out such behavior when it's embedded in good answers or comments.

If any such epithets remain, flag and we'll remove them.

You are a valued member. I've looked over my shoulder as your rep has grown and would likely overtake mine. Rep isn't a gift, it's earned over time. Other members appreciating your sage advice.

Flag what offends you and it will be removed. There's room for some difference of opinion here, but not room for members to insult each other. 
If John or Chris disagree with me, they can comment or edit my answer. I trust their judgement. Same as I've trusted your answers since I joined.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot delete accepted answers, and I'm limited to deleting up to 5 a day. While I've started - it will take me a while. Apparently having a high rep is grounds for being called "troll", "jerk" etc etc, by people who then go and copy my answers. I do not appreciate such behavior. If you cannot provide any other help - I'll have to go and delete everything manually, as long as that may take. I'd appreciate people behaving better, but I acknowledge I have no control over them. I do have control over my own words, and I'm taking everything I've put here down.